# Renaming picture if its already exists

Tags: vba

I have a UserForm to save picture to folder. Please see the code below.

```
Dim strpath As String
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cou As Integer
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
cou = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If cou <> 0 Then
    strpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strpath)
    Image1.PictureSizeMode = 1
End If
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim nam As String
nam = TextBox1.Text
FileCopy strpath, "C:\Desktop\folder\" & nam & ".jpeg"
Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
Set Image1.Picture = Nothing

End Sub
```

How can I write it that do not overwrite the same named file just save it under another name like: Picture1, Picture1-Copy.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way:

```
While Len(Dir("C:\Desktop\folder\" & nam & ".jpeg")) > 0
    nam = nam & 1
Wend
FileCopy strpath, "C:\Desktop\folder\" & nam & ".jpeg"
```

The idea is that if it finds a file like this `sample.jpeg` in `C:\Desktop\folder\`, its length would be bigger than 0. Thus, it would look for file `sample1.jpeg`, `sample11.jpeg`, `sample111.jpeg` and etc. Once it cannot find such a file, it would use the non-found name to save it.